# background image is invisible on browser zoom

Tags: css, cross-browser

I have a single gif image (1px X 1px) which is used as a border for 960 grid framework of my website.

All the layout fits in the correct place in normal state even on increasing the zoom percentage also.

PROBLEM: In case of decreasing the zooming level, border is invisible for certain zoom levels.
e.g. it is visible in 80% but not for 90%.

Is there any cross-browser CSS code OR any other fixes for this issue?
Can we use any specific CSS property to restrict re-sizing background image for browser zoom?

Thanks

Comment: Why use a transparent GIF instead of proper CSS? `border: 1px transparent solid`

Comment: @Pekka: what he means is that the bordersize is adjusted proportionally on zoom out - meaning the border is not always visible

Comment: @pekka Adding CSS-Border breaks the layout on decreasing the zoom. where as background image fixes this issue.

Comment: Breaks the layout? That sounds unusual. When you need to use transparent images to fix a problem,  there's often a deeper layout issue that should be addressed instead. Can you show a link to a live example?

Comment: @M.Bennett I get that - using CSS might fix the issue though, as the browser might treat a CSS border differently when resizing

Comment: @Pekka: You are right. CSS broder property is having issues with the width of the grids while decreasing zoom.

Comment: As said, there is probably a deeper problem here. Post a link if you can